# Question about Partially Ordered Sets and functions

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Could someone verify my attempt at the following problem?

> Let $(A,\preceq)$ and $(B, \preceq ')$ be Partially ordered sets and
>   suppose that $h:A \rightarrow B$ satisfies $x \preceq y \iff h(x) \preceq 'h(y)$ for all $x,y \in A$.Prove that h is one-to-one.

**Attempt:**

Let $(A,\preceq)$ and $(B, \preceq ')$ be POSETS and suppose that $h:A \rightarrow B$ satisfies $x \preceq y \iff h(x)\preceq 'h(y)$ for all $x,y \in A$.

Suppose for a contradiction that $h$ is not one-to-one,then there exists some $x,y \in A$ such that (i) $h(x)=h(y)$ and $x\neq y$.

By anti-symmetry,if $x \preceq y$ and $y \preceq x$ then $x=y$. The logically equivalent contraposition suggests that if $x \neq y$ then $ x \npreceq y$ or $y \npreceq x$.

Since $x \neq y$ by (i) then the following divison by cases are possible.

**[case : $x \npreceq y$ and $y \preceq x$]**

by $x \preceq y \iff h(x)\preceq 'h(y)$ the following holds :

- $x \npreceq y$ implies $h(x)\npreceq 'h(y)$ and
- $y \preceq x$ implies $h(y)\preceq 'h(x)$

therefore with $h(x)\npreceq 'h(y)$ and $h(y)\preceq 'h(x)$ then $h(x) \neq h(y)$ which contradicts (i) according to which $h(x)=h(y)$

**[case : $x \preceq y$ and $y \npreceq x$]**

..similar as the previous case

**[case : $x \npreceq y$ and $y \npreceq x$]**

by $x \preceq y \iff h(x)\preceq 'h(y)$ the following holds :

- $x \npreceq y$ implies $h(x)\npreceq 'h(y)$ and
- $y \npreceq x$ implies $h(y)\npreceq 'h(x)$

therefore with $h(x)\npreceq 'h(y)$ and $h(y)\npreceq 'h(x)$ then $h(x) \neq h(y)$ which contradicts (i) according to which $h(x)=h(y)$.

Therefore h is one-to-one.

---

it looks right but feels iffy to me because for each of the cases i conclude that $h(x) \neq h(y)$ on the bases that

> if $h(x) \preceq 'h(y)$ and $h(y)\preceq 'h(x)$ then $h(x)=h(y)$.

where for example in the last case, $h(x)\npreceq 'h(y)$ and $h(y)\npreceq 'h(x)$ was implied to yield $h(x) \neq h(y)$
...is that logically right ?

thank you for your time.

Comment: The antisymmetry is indeed all you need.

Comment: Thank you, the reason i used contradiction is due to confusion of the meaning of 'if' ,'only if' in definitions as opposed to in theorems,corollaries,lemmas....is my proof still correct though?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need proof by contradiction

$$h(x)=h(y)$$
$$\Longrightarrow h(x)\preceq^{\prime}h(y)\:\land\:h(y)\preceq^{\prime}h(x)$$
$$\Longrightarrow x\preceq y\:\land\:y\preceq x$$
$$\Longrightarrow x=y$$

Comment: No need to work with a contradiction: $h(x) = h(y)$ implies $x = y$ as you showed, so $h$ is one-to-one.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Indeed, was in the middle of editing my answer.

Comment: Yes! That was the confusion i had. In mathematical defintions, it seems that 'if' and 'only if' statements should be regarded as 'iff'..which is why i used proof by contradiction and why i highlighted my concerns about things being iffy...after browsing the internet it seems that technically, occurences of 'if' , 'only if' in mathematical definitions linking A and B, imply that A and B are synonymous hence practically one can treat such statements  as A iff B...am i understanding this right? Also, is my proof by contradiction okay? Thanks